# How to convert PImage to Byte [] in Processing

Tags: php, web, save, processing

There is a way to convert PImage variables into Byte Arrays? I need to do this to send the array to a PHP Script and Upload the file. I already saw the  Saving files to a web: http://wiki.processing.org/w/Saving_files_to_a_web_server 
But there are some functions that processing says that doesn't exist: bufferImage()

Answer (score 0):

Processing.org user [PhilHo](https://forum.processing.org/user/philho) posted this code, which should work:
To access the int array of a PImage you just have to call `myPimage.loadPixels(); int[] data = myPImage.pixels[];`

```
 import java.nio.*;

 void setup()
 {

   int[] data = { 100, 200, 300, 400 };

   ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length * 4);       
   IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
   intBuffer.put(data);

   byte[] array = byteBuffer.array();

   println(array);

 }
```